# How do I ask screen to behave like a standard bash shell?

Tags: bash, gnu-screen, xterm

Just learned about the screen command on linux - it is genius.  I love it.  However, the actual terminal/prompt in screen looks and behaves differently than my standard bash prompt.  That is, the colors aren't the same, tab completion doesn't seem to work, etc.

Is there a way I can tell screen to behave just like a normal (at least, normal as in what I am used to) bash prompt ?

#### Additional Information

I am connecting via ssh from a Mac (Terminal) to a headless linux box (Ubuntu). After logging in, I have `TERM=xterm-color` and when I run screen I have `TERM=screen`.

Am going to try the suggestions below to see if I can change the `$TERM` value first.

Comment: Just out of curiosity what OS, and what type of terminal do you have when start screen?  I would guess your issues has more to do with your Terminal doing something wrong or identifying incorrectly to screen.

Comment: @Zoredache - I added that information to the post, above.  Thanks.  I did have to adjust my Terminal's settings to allow the backspace key to work ...

Comment: Yuck, I really don't like Terminal.app.  Personally I suggest you consider using an alternative see (http://serverfault.com/questions/19240/poll-what-is-your-favourite-terminal-program)

Answer (score 49):

Thanks to [this post](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=82519), what I did was add one line to `~/.screenrc`:

```
# ~/.screenrc
defshell -bash      # dash makes it a login shell
```

Then things in your `~/.bashrc`, `/etc/bashrc`, etc. should get run.

Comment: ^ This is the answer! Worked for me!

Comment: Note that this will set your `$SHELL` to `bash` (no path). You can actually do `shell -/bin/bash` in your `~/.screenrc` which will set `$SHELL` to `/bin/bash` -- that works better if a program tries to use `execv` on the value. (OpenSSH ProxyCommand, I'm looking at you). Also since you can't change this value dynamically, `defshell` and `shell` are the same.

Answer (score 14):

screen changes the term-type to `screen`. You can do one of two things:

1. change the term setting in your `.screenrc`
2. modify your `.bashrc` files look for `TERM=screen` as well as `TERM=xterm`

Comment: Thanks!  I created a `$HOME/.screenrc` file and added this line to the top: `term xterm-color` and wa la! Color prompt and the `$TERM` values match.  However, no tab-completion ...

Comment: You need to dig into what turns the tab-completion on. The default shell configuration scripts are not entirely consistent about what they enable based on `$TERM`; some things will enable with xterm as well as xterm-color, others only look for xterm. Other things have other switches.

Answer (score 12):

I like the way you wrote your question, I was asking myself the same thing and it took a little while to figure it out. I was fortunate to already know a little about shell invocation, so I figured the problem lay there somewhere.

Here are my findings. Firstly, I personally find it interesting and worth knowing the difference between a login shell and a non-login shell. Do a `man $SHELL` and search for the section on INVOCATION to read more about it.

You can ask your current shell instance if its a login shell or non-login shell by issuing a `shopt login_shell` on your prompt. Note this is normally a read only option.

On my Debian systems, `screen` has always come defaulted with non-login shells.

After searching the web and reading `man $SHELL`, I tested a few things out and the following two approaches worked for me. In `~/.screenrc` add/update a line as follows:

```
shell -$SHELL
```

If that doesn't work out AND you are using `bash`, you can alternatively try, as shared by [Seamus](https://serverfault.com/users/82254/seamus-abshere):

```
defshell -bash
```

As mentioned, you can test if your current shell instance is a login shell by issuing `shopt login_shell` on your prompt.

Comment: Is the way to have the shell launch in the current directory?  An example of what I desire is the following `cd ~/Projects ; screen ; pwd #=> ~/Projects`.  However, what I get after adding `shell -$SHELL` to my `~/.screenrc` is `cd ~/Projects ; screen ; pwd #=> ~/`

Answer (score 10):

Depending on how you're used to running Bash, you may be running a login shell. When you run `screen`, you're running a non-login interactive shell.

The difference is in which startup scripts are run.

- `/etc/bash.bashrc` then `~/.bashrc` are sourced when a non-login interactive shell is started
- `/etc/profile` then the first found of `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bash_login`, and `~/.profile` are sourced when an interactive login shell is started

This may be affecting you.

I would also check to see if `$TERM` is different.

Answer (score 3):

screen doesn't replace bash, it runs it, or any other shell. maybe it's running `csh`, `zsh`, or `bash` but with different paramters.

the first thing i would try is to check with `ps` and `/proc/<pid>/cmdline` to be sure that it's using the same shell with same parameters as `login` does.

after that, check `/etc/screenrc` and any other file mentioned at `man screen` FILES section.

Comment: I ran a `ps` command and it shows that `bash` is running (this is a ps command inside of screen) ... I got the color working (above) just need tab completion.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, when I ran screen I lost the cool PS1 color prompt I had craftily found :P.

Issue is I was running it like this in ~/.bash_profile

```
PS1="\[\033[35m\]\t\[\033[m\]-\[\033[36m\]\u\[\033[m\]@\[\033[32m\]\h:\[\033[33;1m\]\w\[\033[m\]\$ "
```

That means that when screen was running the bash_profile the PS1 is not being carried over.

Fix is easy: add export to the PS1 statement in the ~./bash_profile to look like this :

```
export PS1="\[\033[35m\]\t\[\033[m\]-\[\033[36m\]\u\[\033[m\]@\[\033[32m\]\h:\[\033[33;1m\]\w\[\033[m\]\$ "
```

Like that the variable is not lost in the nested execution.

Answer (score 2):

Just want to add something about "defshell -bash" (which I just figured out, after months of head-scratching).  When you do that, the child shell run by screen has $SHELL set to "bash", instead of "/bin/bash" like it normally would be.  If you then run "script" inside your screen session, you get:

```
$ script
Script started, file is typescript
script: failed to execute bash: No such file or directory
```

Or at least that's what happens on my Ubuntu 14.04 box.  The workaround I've been using is to run `$ SHELL=/bin/bash script`.  I would imagine having $SHELL set wrong will break other stuff, but script is what I've noticed.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using this snippet in my `.profile` before any shell initialization is started:

```bash
[ "$( which screen 2> /dev/null )" ] && {
    # Uncomment for old screen's (exit codes are lower by one)
    #_old_screen_base=9
    screen -q -ls
    if [ $? -gt ${_old_screen_base:-10} ]; then
        read -p "$(tput setaf 2)Found a running SCREEN sesion, attach?$(tput sgr0)[Y/n] " y >&2
        if [ "${y:-y}" = "y" -o "$y" = "Y" ]; then
            exec screen -aDR
        fi
    else
        echo "$(tput setaf 3)No attachable SCREEN sessions found.$(tput sgr0)" >&2
    fi
}
```

Then, if there's no screen session is running, I… well, I just fall into standard shell prompt. If I plan to perform a lengthy task, I launch screen manually in my user's session and if I get disconnected, I just hop back and say "yes" to attach prompt.

The key point here is "before any shell initialization", so that when you already have a running screen session, it is already initialized with locale and other stuff and you do not need to redo it again.