# screen -R not working with ssh

Tags: linux, ssh, gnu-screen

I have a linux box in the office I want to ssh into from my Macbook at home.  I can’t reach the box directly on port 22, but I have a port tunnel nailed up between localhost:23001 and port 22 on the remote linux box.  This works for a regular ssh session:

```
$ ssh -t -2 -A -p 23001 roysmith@127.0.0.1
```

The next step is, I want to automatically run my terminal session inside a screen session.  It almost works to do:

```
$ ssh -t -2 -A -p 23001 roysmith@127.0.0.1  screen -R
```

If I don’t have a current screen session, it creates one.  If there’s already a detached screen, it connects to it.  So far, so good.  But, the problem is, I never get a login shell, so my .profile never gets run and my environment doesn’t get set up.  So, I went one step further, and tried:

```
$ ssh -t -2 -A -p 23001 roysmith@127.0.0.1  bash -l -c screen -R
```

Now, I get a real login shell which runs .profile, but screen fails to re-attach to a detached session.  I run the above command on my Macbook, and on the remote machine, I’ve got an attached screen:

```
$ screen -list
There is a screen on:
    21117.pts-21.roysmith01 (01/19/2015 01:50:59 PM)    (Attached)
1 Socket in /var/run/screen/S-roysmith.
```

If I close the window where I ran the above ssh line, the session gets detached, as expected:

```
$ screen -list
There is a screen on:
    21117.pts-21.roysmith01 (01/19/2015 01:50:59 PM)    (Detached)
1 Socket in /var/run/screen/S-roysmith.
```

Now, if I open another local terminal window and run that ssh command again, screen fails to find the detached session and creates a new one:

```
$ screen -list
There are screens on:
    21304.pts-21.roysmith01 (01/19/2015 01:52:40 PM)    (Attached)
    21117.pts-21.roysmith01 (01/19/2015 01:50:59 PM)    (Detached)
2 Sockets in /var/run/screen/S-roysmith.
```

Any idea what’s going on here?  Why does inserting a login shell keep screen from locating existing sessions?

Comment: Have you checked the permissions on the sockets in /var/run/screen?  What happens if you use 'screen -D -RR' instead?

Comment: -D -RR still doesn't attach to an existing session; it generates a new one.  I just generated three sessions, one with "screen -R", one with "bash -l -c screen -R", and one with "bash -l -C screen -D -RR".  They all generate the same permissions:

```
$ ls -l /var/run/screen/S-roysmith/
total 0
prwx------ 1 roysmith eng 0 Jan 19 18:02 32644.pts-20.roysmith01
prwx------ 1 roysmith eng 0 Jan 19 18:03 468.pts-28.roysmith01
prwx------ 1 roysmith eng 0 Jan 19 18:06 760.pts-22.roysmith01
```

Answer (score 1):

If there is no existing session to connect to, screen will use whatever command you give *after* the `-R` flag. So this should do what you want (without having to touch .screenrc):

```
$ ssh [...]@127.0.0.1 screen -R bash -l
```

(This is surely the simplest way to do what you originally set out to do.)

But since you asked, I'll also mention why your `bash -l` approach didn't work. It was so close!

`bash -c` takes only the very next argument as a command. Arguments after that go into `$0`, `$1`, etc.

```
$ bash -c echo bar
[just a blank line]
$ bash -c 'echo foo'
foo
$ bash -c 'echo $1' foo bar baz
bar
```

This does what you wanted `bash -l -c screen -R` to do:

```
$ ssh [...]@127.0.0.1 bash -l -c "'screen -R'"
```

Yes, excitingly you do need two levels of quoting for that to work: the outer quotes tell your local shell to preserve the inner quotes, and the inner quotes are needed because ssh sends the resulting command, `bash -l -c 'screen -R'`, as a string with four spaces in it, not as a list of four words. With one level of quotes, the remote shell would still see `bash -l -c screen -R`.

This would do it too, with the remote shell being given the command string `bash -l -c screen\ -R`:

```
$ ssh [...]@127.0.0.1 bash -l -c 'screen\ -R'
```

Or this, to give the remote shell `bash -l -c "screen -R"`:

```
$ ssh [...]@127.0.0.1 bash -l -c \"screen -R\"
```

Answer (score 0):

I found [How do I ask screen to behave like a standard bash shell?](https://serverfault.com/questions/126009/how-do-i-ask-screen-to-behave-like-a-standard-bash-shell), which pointed me in the right direction.  Putting "defshell -bash" in my .screenrc gets me the behavior I want.  With I could figure out what screen is really doing, however.  I hate finding things that work without understanding why.